# Is $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ open or closed in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, continuity

As the title says. I have to say whether $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is open or closed in $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ (it's open because it's $\text{det}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\})$, preimage of an openset by a continuous function) and if it's open or closed in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$.

I suspect it's closed since I know $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^4$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}^4 \cong \mathbb{R}^8$ and $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}) = M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \cap \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Does it make sense?

Comment: @DietrichBurde This looks like an overkill to me. Maybe OP is not familiar with topological groups at all, it's not a necessary knowledge for this problem. A direct, simple argument can be used to show that $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Not every question that can be solved with more advanced tools is a duplicate.

Comment: OP, since this is a metric space, just show that if you take a convergent sequence from $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, its limit also belongs to $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$. This is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Mark yep you're right I haven't studied topological groups yet. I can see how the argument with the convergent succession works. Does mine work too? I was hoping for a "topological" answer in the sense that it doesn't involve metric spaces' properties, however that's fine too.

Comment: You are asking about being open or closed. Note that these notions are not mutually exclusive. To see that $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not open in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$, look at a neighborhood of the identity matrix. For your argument about being closed. For closedness, you seem to say that $\mathrm{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $\mathrm{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$ and thus, in the subspace topology of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ we have that $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})=\mathrm{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\cap \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is closed. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] This argument is fine as soon as you have a rigorous proof that $\mathrm{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $\mathrm{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$. Your identification does not really accomplish that as it is written now. In any case, Mark's way of doing it would be substantially easier.

Comment: You know what? This is a great question for a course in topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To formalize your argument that $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$ is closed in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb C)$, recall that the imaginary part map $\Im: M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb C) \to M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb R)$ is continuous (in fact, it is ($\Bbb R$-)linear). So, $\Im^{-1}({\bf 0}_{2 \times 2}) = M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb R)$ is closed (it is the preimage of a singleton), hence $M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb R) \cap \operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb C) = \operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$ is closed in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb C) \subset M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb C)$.

To determine whether $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$ is open in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb C)$, notice that $(1 + \epsilon i) {\bf 1}_{2 \times 2}$ is only in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$ for $\epsilon = 0$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Minor nitpick, I think you are missing a "is continuous" after defining your map.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks, I fixed the omission.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you very much.